# How can i compare two array with php by loop and use of in_array()?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is table format:
table1 user_language:

```
      id    user_id   lang_id   status
    -------------------------------------
      1      20         1        1
      2      21         1        1
      3      21         2        0
      4      21         3        1
```

table2  languages:

```
     id    name
    ---------------
      1     English
      2     hindi
      3    Gujarati
      4    italian
```

Model code:

```
     function select_user_language($user_id){$this->db->select('lang_id'); $this->db->from('user_language');$this->db->where('user_id ',$user_id); $this->db->where('status ',1); $query = $this->db->get();return $query->result(); }
     function  fins_status_user_lang($user_id,$lang_id){
       $this->db->select('*');
       $this->db->from('user_language');
       $this->db->where('user_id ',$user_id);
       $this->db->where('lang_id ',$lang_id);
       $this->db->where('status ',0);
       $query = $this->db->get();
       return $query->result();
    }
     function insert_user_lang($dta_sport){
       $this->db->insert('user_language',$dta_sport);
    }
    function change_status_user_lang($lang_id,$user_id,$status) {
    $sql = "UPDATE user_language SET status = '".$status."' WHERE lang_id = '".$lang_id."' and user_id='".$user_id."'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    if($query){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
    }
```

Controller Code:

```
     $this->load->model('user/user_model');
    $user_id = $this->input->post('lang_id');
    $query1 = $this->user_model->select_user_language($user_id);
    $lang_var = $this->input->post('lang');//user selected language in array for example: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 4 ) 
    $arr = array();
    if($lang_var != ""){
        $var1[] = "";
        $var2[] = "";
        foreach ($query1 as $row=>$value) {
            $lang_type = explode(',', $value->lang_id);
            foreach ($lang_var as $search) {
                if (in_array($search, $lang_type)) {
                 $query2 = $this->user_model->change_status_user_lang($search,$user_id,$status=1);
                }
                else {
                   $find = $this->user_model->fins_status_user_lang($user_id,$search);
                    if($find){
                        $query3 = $this->user_model->change_status_user_lang($search,$user_id,$status=1);
                    } else {
                        $dta_sport['user_id'] = $user_id;
                        $dta_sport['lang_id'] = $search;
                        $dta_sport['status'] = 1;
                        $this->user_model->insert_user_lang($dta_sport);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

my problem is how can i compare user_language table data (for example Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [lang_id] => 1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [lang_id] => 2 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [lang_id] => 16 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [lang_id] => 7 ) )) like this and user selected language (for example Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 5 [3] => 7 [4] => 16 ) ) like this. Now i want to change status field of user_language table if user selected language than 1 otherwise 0. or user select new language which is not present in user_language table than make new entry in user_language table means insert that language.
Please give me some quick solution for my problem.

Comment: Is it not working ? What is the problem ? insert/update ?

Comment: yes.. insert update is my problem how can i compare user selected value with already entered value in table.. how can i change status if it is zero? how can i insert new entry if language is not there in user_language

Comment: Why not use `array_diff()`?

Comment: i try array_diff() but it's not give me proper result.